# Read files in folder and then do something by groovy

Tags: groovy

I have write a script to read the file and then do something from specified path:

```
def file = new File(/"a.txt"/)
def s = []
s = file.filterLine  { it.contains("project ")}
def array = []
def a = []
array << s.toString().split(/(<|=|:|"|,|\/>)/)
a = array.find{ it.contains("SYN_3-1_M5_integration")}
b = a.findAll { it.startsWith("SYN_3")}
println b.unique()
```

I just want to asked if I have a lot of txt file how can I use above code. I am a newbie in Groovy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what You'd like to do. You'd like to process multiple files at once and asking how to change the code to do such processing?

Comment: I want to read files in specified forlder and import something which start with `SYN_3` to array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following piece of code should do the job:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

new File('PATH_TO_FOLDER').eachFile(FileType.FILES) { file ->
    def s = []
    s = file.filterLine  { it.contains("project ")} 
    def array = []
    def a = []
    array << s.toString().split(/(<|=|:|"|,|\/>)/)
    println array.toString() 
    a = array.find{ it.contains("SYN_3-1_M5_integration")} 
    println a
    b = a.findAll { it.startsWith("SYN_3")} 
    println b.unique()
}
```

Basically it iterates over each file in folder specified with *PATH_TO_FOLDER* and do the processing in the way it was posted.

Comment: Thanks! that's very helpful. One more thing, in my script, when I use 
`println b.unique()`
it display like: 
`[SYN_3-1_M3, SYN_3-1_M3_2ndEdn]`
`[SYN_3-1_M4_integration, SYN_3-1_M3, SYN_3-1_M4_integration1]`

I want it everything should have to be in `b`. I have changed
`b << a.findAll { it.startsWith("SYN_3")} ` 
 But it seem not correct. Could you please help me.

Comment: It seems what `flatten` is what You're looking for: `assert [[1,2],3,[4,5]].flatten() == [1,2,3,4,5]`